# Make it harder to switch tabs in TabView when displaying WebView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a `TabView` that is scrollable both horizontally (switching tabs) and vertically (scrolling the content). One of the tabs contains a `WebView`.

The users have a problem with scrolling the website, because horizontal scroll is too sensitive and they start switching tabs instead.

How to make the horizontal scroll less sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

Add `gestureRecognizers` as a `WebView` parameter:

```dart
WebView(
  gestureRecognizers: {
    Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
            () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer()
    )
  },
  initialUrl: widget.url,
);
```

As mentioned here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33565

And explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RA-vLF_vnng